# byte array multiplication

Tags: c#, multiplication

This is my code - its classic multiplication A*B = C

```
private static int MASK = 0x00ff;
public static int multiplication(byte[] A, byte[] B, byte[] R)
{
    byte n = 0;
    int bb;
    int sum = 0;
    int lenbyte = 0;

    for (int c = 0; c < R.Length; c++) //R set 0
    {
        R[c] = 0;
    }

    int j = B.Length - 1;
    int i = 0;

    do //cycles go throught bytes of B from LSB to MSB
    {
       bb = B[j] & MASK;
       if (bb != 0x00)
       {
          i = A.Length - 1;
          n = 0x00; //carry byte

          do //cycles throught bytes of A from LSB to MSB
          {
              sum = ((A[i] & MASK) * bb) + (R[i + j+1 ]&MASK) + (n & MASK);
              R[i + j+1] = (byte)(sum & MASK);
              n = (byte)((uint)sum >> 8);
              i--;
          } while (i >= 0);
          R[j] = n;
          j--;
       }
       else
       {
          R[j] = 0x00;
          j--;
       }
    } while (j >= 0);

    return 1;
}
```

It works bad. I think that problem is in bitwise.
I thanks for yours ideas. :)

Comment: Can you be more specific on the problem? What part doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your code takes A and B as input and returns the output in R right? Well the way you coded it doesn't work. You are passing R as a parameter to the scope of the multiplication function. That means that once the function hits a return all the memory used by this function will be freed and R will be cleared. Also you are using passing by parameter which, in C#, makes a copy of the original parameter to use it in the function and doesn't change the original variable.

What you can do to fix it is either pass the parameter by reference:

```
public static int multiplication(byte[] A, byte[] B, ref byte[] R)
{
...
```

Or you can return the value as the intended return of the function which would be like this:

```
public static byte[] multiplication(byte[] A, byte[] B)
{
byte[] R; // define this and give it the correct size

// add your code here

return R;
}
```

Comment: Arrays are always passed by reference. Unless you want to assign a new array inside the method, using ref is not necessary. I don't see any `R = new byte[n];` in his code

Comment: I didn't look through the whole code but I'll try it right now. I'm kinda sure that even "Reference types" get GCed when a function returns. At least in C# that is.

Comment: Yea, but his arrays are initialized and referenced outside of his method. Only a **copy of the reference** is passed to the method, but both references point to the same array object on the Heap. Arrays in .NET are saved on the heap, and objects in heap are by reference. To clarify: `R[0] = 5;` also changes his array outside (if it's initialized of course, otherwise you'll get `NullReferenceException` or `IndexOutOfRangeException`. `R = new byte[A.Length];` won't work in his case, because this would reassign the reference (the reference is passed by copy, but not the array).

Comment: I think out is more suited then ref because ref is read and write-able but out is just writeable though it works all the same.